# Tips and advice for topology? Having troubles to design complex structures in stylized manner

Tags: topology

I just discovered an art style i really like and enjoy doing, which is lazy/gradient texturing. I tasked myself to model and practice whenever possible and i have this personal quest to model in my style all zelda items. I have already made the bottle and bomb using this style, heres them:
[image]
[image]

Id say theyre all pretty neat. The problem is with the clawshot item. Its ok for most of its topology EXCEPT the claws aka the things that latch onto surfaces. I tried two times to model them but didnt quite land it:

[image]
[image]

Any tips that I could have? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: This seems a little unfocused right now.  Does your texturing impact the topology you want to use?  What are the problems with the claw topology that you're running into?  What you're showing looks perfectly reasonable for the style that you're after.  The only advice I might offer is, inset the tip of each finger, then bisect the remaining hexagon to make two quads, but flat shaded + unsubdivided like you're showing, it really doesn't matter.